# ASP.NET CORE Irepository

Tags: asp.net-core, repository, реализация

Много где видел реализацию многоуровневой архитектуры но нигде в реализации интерфейса IRepository не используется асинхронные методы.
Вот пример реализации из одного источника:

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T Get(int id);
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, Boolean> predicate);
        void Create(T item);
        void Update(T item);
        void Delete(int id);
    }
```

Ведь методы GetAll, Get, Find, Create  могут быть асинхронными.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
        {
            Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync();
            Task<T> GetAsync(int id);
            Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAsync(Func<T, Boolean> predicate);
            Task CreateAsync(T item);
            void Update(T item);
            void Delete(int id);
        }
```

Почему нигде не используется асинхронность в многослойной архитектуре или она не работает на этом уровне?

Comment: Вам никто не мешает сделать их асинхронными....но обычно на запрос CRUD ожидается ответ. И пока вы его будите жать - все равно операция будет синхронной..так есть ли смысл

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц а разве поток который делает запрос, не освобождается при асинхронном запросе?

Comment: В каком смысле "освобождается"?...тут даже скорее наоборот, он напрягается )

Comment: Работает. Только ее и использую. И всем настоятельно рекомендую в asp.net то